# SVG zoom and scroll gesture

Tags: android, svg-android

I have a simple activity which display a fullscreen SVG thanks to [this](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/)
 android lib. The SVG displayed is a map and I need to enable zoom/scroll gesture on it. That is why I use [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) lib, which works perfectly with normal ImageView.

Here, I'm using PhotoView lib attacher to SVGImageView :

```
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    SVGImageView svgImageView = new SVGImageView(this);
    svgImageView.setImageAsset("map.svg");
    layout.addView(svgImageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(layout);

    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(svgImageView);
}
```

PhotoView works but it takes like 10 second to apply zoom or scroll gesture.

Do you have any ideas on how I could efficiently scale & scroll in ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `SVGImageView` ? it is not part of the svg lib you use? http://svg-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/svgandroid/docs/index.html

Comment: Sorry I maybe linked the wrong lib it´s this one : https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/wiki/SVGImageView